# php version install issues for terminal and phpinfo()

Tags: php, apache

In my terminal put that command

```
# php -v
```

i am getting

```
PHP 5.6.23-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

but in my localhost phpinfo();
i am getting 5.5.9

```
PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
```

how can i got 5.6 in locahost phpinfo();
i am using localhost wamp server in ubundu os..

Comment: Wamp provides a range of php versions for you tu use, there usually is no visible difference between some of them, but if you really need to use a specific version, you can try upgrading wamp
Or installing the LAMP stack all by yourself, which is easy since you're on ubuntu

Comment: I already updated in ubundu but it will affect only terminal not in localhost

Answer (score 1):

The PHP application and the Apache server will load different `php.ini` files,
wamp provides one in the apache directory and php itself will use the one in it's own php directory (where the apps are located)

To check that, you can do `php -i | grep php.ini` and compare it to the `loaded Configuration File` you get from your browser when using `phpinfo()`

To work around this issue, either install LAMP yourself, or try to link the two files together somehow.

[Reference to another Stack Overflow question on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917099/different-php-versions-showing-in-terminal-and-browser-in-ubuntu-11-10)