# Install SOAP Extension PHP Config (AWS)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I included `extension=php_soap.dll` at the bottom of my PHP configuration file, however I get the error below.  Where do I put the command?

> "Invalid command 'extension=php_soap.dll', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"

Using an AWS server

Comment: Can you also paste the last couple on lines from your `php.ini` file?

Answer (score 8):

No need to add any lines in the PHP configuration file.

This lists the modules available for install:

```
$ yum search php | grep -i soap
```

This installs the module "php-soap"

```
$ sudo yum install php-soap
```

Then restart the server

```
$ sudo service httpd restart
$ sudo service php-fpm restart // if needed
```

All info taken from:
[How do I enable --enable-soap in php on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584426/how-do-i-enable-enable-soap-in-php-on-linux)

Answer (score 6):

For PHP 5.6 it's `php56-soap`, so the command goes like this:

`$ sudo yum install php56-soap`