# How to enable SOAP client in PHP on Pressmatic

Tags: linux, nginx, soap, debian, php-7

I need to enable the SOAP Client in PHP7 on a [Pressmatic](https://pressmatic.io/) Docker instance. I already figure out how to het `apt-get install php7.0-soap` working by [adding the proper repositories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802989/failed-to-install-php7-0-soap-on-ubuntu).

Unfortunately I can't figure out the next steps. The SOAP Client is still not visible in `phpinfo()`.

The machine is running PHP 7.0.3 and nginx.

`lsb_release -a` gives me this:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.4 (jessie)
Release:    8.4
Codename:   jessie
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install this module in NGINX using a CLI.

see: [How do I enable --enable-soap in php on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584426/how-do-i-enable-enable-soap-in-php-on-linux)

Comment: Thanks. I did all this, but it doesn't explain how to make it available in PHP7.