# Want to install SOAP on PHP5.5

Tags: soap, symfony-1.4, ubuntu-16.04, php-5.5

I am working on ubuntu 16.04 with PHP version 5.5 now I want to use SOAP library in it.

I have already installed php-soap package(with ref. [How do I enable --enable-soap in php on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584426/how-do-i-enable-enable-soap-in-php-on-linux)) and tried to enable it. but it won't works for me anyway.

By searching I found php soap package are available for PHP version 5.6, 7.0, 7.1.but am working on PHP version 5.5 and in situation that I can't change PHP version of my system.

Any way or suggestion to install soap for PHP5.5 would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

The SOAP package is available for all versions of PHP since at least 4 something. There are two options on how to install/enable it depending on the way your PHP was installed initially.

If your PHP was installed via the distribution's package manager you just have to install the package `php-soap`. On your Ubuntu this should be:
`sudo apt-get install php-soap`

If your PHP was compiled on your machine you will have to compile it again passing in the switch `--enable-soap` .This switch could differ depending on your PHP verison. Check the documentation of make in PHP's source if this is the case.

Comment: Thanks @Borislav but as I told I have already tried with sudo apt-get install php-soap and soap is already installed in my machine but its installed for PHP7.1 as its latest PHP version in my ubuntu16.04. if I do list for php-soap version then I get it available for PHP5.6, PHP7.0, PHP7.1 but not getting it for PHP5.5 thats the problem

Comment: How can I do some enable soap command with PHP5.5  on ubuntu 16.04? any idea would be great help