# SOAP not enabled on PHP5.5 version

Tags: php, soap

The website portal I am working on is using PHP 5.5. Now, I am required to communicate to a SOAP server. I am trying to work this out using the **soapClient** on PHP. However, the PHP installed does not seem to have SOAP client. I tried locating it with phpinfo(). It does not show the SOAP module.

I have tried some solutions such as uncommenting *extension=php_soap.dll* and restarting apache2 server.

I have even tried to install SOAP, however, it only installs SOAP for PHP7.0 version. I am not able to find the SOAP version for PHP 5.5

Comment: You may need to search a bit PHP 5.5 is a bit old now

Comment: http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for the response. I have been searching, but cannot find SOAP for PHP 5.5

Comment: @hakre Thanks for the link. However, I am working on Ubuntu and I am looking for SOAP install for 5.5

Comment: You are trying to enable a .dll file on linux?
Then it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584426/how-do-i-enable-enable-soap-in-php-on-linux

Comment: @RubenVincenten I have tried their solution previously but it did not work for me probably because of my PHP version

Comment: That's perhaps more a sysadmin question then and better suited on a different Q&A site. And setting the extension ini directive to a (obviously non-existent) .dll file on linux is really, really wrong. .dll files are shared libraries on windows. on linux, this are .so files. Best bet is that you use your operating systems package manager to install the php soap extension. Lean on existing resources, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/11584426/367456 - also consult your operating systems documentation and resources about the topic.